# Windows 10 won't boot from grub

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, boot, grub

I currently have Linux Mint installed along Windows 10, and both have been working harmoniously together for a good 6 months. This morning, I attempted to select Windows 10 from the grub menu as I do every morning, and was greeted with the error

```
/EndEntire
file path: /ACPI(a0341d0,0)/PCI...
error: cannot load image

Press any key to continue...
```

Apparently one of the most common causes of this error is [not having secure boot disabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377979/windows-8-uefi-does-not-boot); however I'd already encountered this program the first time I installed Linux and hence secure boot is still disabled. [boot-repair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280339/windows-8-wont-boot-via-grub-after-installing-ubuntu-with-boot-repair) has also been suggested, so I installed and ran that. After running `boot-repair`, my grub options had expanded to

```
Linux Min 18 Cinnamon 64-bit
Advanced options for Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit
Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi
Windows Boot UEFI loader
EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi
EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p2)
System Setup
```

Selecting either `Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi` or `Windows Boot Manager` yielded the same error as before. However, selecting `Windows Boot UEFI loader` resulted in a BSOD-like screen along the lines of

```
Recovery
Your PC/Device needs to be repaired
There is an invalid object in the Boot Configuration Data store
Error code 0xc0000034
```

I'm hesitant to proceed with further troubleshooting on my own as i'm rapidly getting out of my depth and don't want to make things worse. Do i need do something along the lines of running `bcdboot` from a Windows Live CD, or is this a problem with `grub`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For historical purposes, I thought i'd mention I bit the bullet and ran

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

from a Windows install medium. This did the trick - Windows now boots via `Windows Boot UEFI loader` in `grub` (`grub` itself was not corrupted at all).